# How do i boot from a live usb?

Tags: live-usb

SOLVED
SOLVED
SOLVED

So i just made a liveUSB on my ubuntu but i have no clue how to use it now! I plug it in the usb socket and...nothing happens.
I tried searchincg online but couldn't find anything on using a liveUSB.

Info: i did NOT ask in any way on "how to make a liveUSB. I asked on "how to USE a live usb"...
I know know how to use such a live usb. I have another problem/question now but i will create another topic/ask for that. Thank you all for trying to help, and thanks even more for those who did help! Ron, Sidharth Sethu and chill555...thanks. And thanks to the others too.

Please tell me what to do, thanks

Comment: Plugin the USB and restart your computer. watch for a message telling you which key to press to enter the BIOS setup. It can be  F1, F2, DEL, ESC or F10, F12, F9 or someother. Find the option to change the boot device and select usb from it

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a live USB, restart your computer. Enter the computer's BIOS using the Esc or F1 key or whatever allows access to the BIOS. Under bootup options or similar, be sure that booting from USB is enabled. Make sure the boot priority has USB first. Save the new settings, if any, and proceed to boot. You will then boot into Ubuntu on the USB rather than the operating system on the harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

A LiveUSB is used to boot a computer system, plainly plugging it into a computer as a normal flash drive would be of no help.
To boot from a LiveUSB, you need to **ensure that**:

1. You know which key to press at startup, which will take you to the BIOS setup.
2. Booting from USB is enabled. This is mostly not an option, as booting from a USB is enabled by default.

At startup, you need to press the hotkey, enter the boot options, and select the USB as the device to boot from.

The problem with rearranging the boot order is that in future, if you try to boot your system with a USB plugged in it may cause problems.
So the above mentioned technique should work just fine.
Cheers!